# C# + threading + serial ports + lock

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port

I have to write code which creates two threads for a project. One thread processes information, accessed by a static list, which is received by an event handler and the thread then has to send some data out to the serial port. The other thread has to wait for the user to input data on the console screen and then send data to the same serial port. How do I create a second thread to run in the baackground? How do I allow this thread to send data to the serial port? How do I create a lock so that the background thread pauses while the event handler adds new information to the static list?

Comment: Have you tried something so far?

Comment: To create a lock create a shared object and lock on it.

Comment: To create a Task you can use: System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { your code here });

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stackoverflow is mostly for seeking answers to questions that arise from specific difficulties. If you are looking for more tutorial type solutions, check out sites like CodeProject. For example:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/75770/Basic-serial-port-listening-application

Comment: Your question/s are a little unclear, but bear in mind that serial ports are usually slow.  Instead of locking over the entire serial send call, queue your serial data onto a producer-consumer queue and have another thread pop it and send it.

Comment: Just don't, you get no benefit whatsoever from a second thread.  Just call SerialPort.Write() in your main thread.  You typically only need a thread for reading the port, you already get one for free from the DataReceived event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to have the main thread handle the user input and a background thread processing information. Both of those format the data that needs to go to the serial port and puts that data on a queue. A third thread removes data from the queue and writes it to the serial port.

The queue is a [BlockingCollection<string>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx), a concurrent data structure that can handle multiple readers and writers.

The benefit of this is that you have no explicit locking so you eliminate a bunch of potential multithreading hazards. The processing thread doesn't block to output, but rather just puts data on the queue and continues. This allows processing to happen at full speed.

It also prevents the potential delay that would occur if the user typed something and then the program had to wait for the processor's message to be sent and then for his message to be sent.

Note that the collection could be a `BlockingCollection<byte[]>` if the data you're sending over the serial port is binary rather than a string.

This creates one more thread than you absolutely *need*, but in my opinion it's a much cleaner design.

So you have:

```
private BlockingCollection<string> outputQueue = new BlockingCollection<string>();

// the thread that processes information
private void DataProcessor()
{
    // initialization
    // process data
    while ()
    {
        string foo = CreateOutputFromData();
        // put it on the queue
        outputQueue.Add(foo);
    }
}

// the output thread
private void OutputThread()
{
    // initialize serial port
    // read data from queue until end
    string text;
    while (outputQueue.TryTake(out text, Timeout.Infinite))
    {
        // output text to serial port
    }
}

// main thread
public Main()
{
    // create the processing thread
    var processingThread = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DataProcessor(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    // create the output thread
    var outputThread = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => OutputThread(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

    // wait for user input and process
    while ()
    {
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        // potentially process input before sending it out
        var dataToOutput = ProcessInput(input);
        // put it on the queue
        outputQueue.Add(dataToOutput);
    }

    // tell processing thread to exit

    // when you're all done, mark the queue as finished
    outputQueue.CompleteAdding();

    // wait for the threads to exit.
    Task.WaitAll(outputThread, processingThread);   
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is an amazing response. I have completed my code, thank you!